# Replit error with google API but works in Pycharm

Tags: python, api, drive

I was  following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python#trouble
I followed every step (has some trouble with creating credentials but got it working) but at the last step, it gave me an error. At Step 3.2 it says "a. Click Accept. The app is authorized to access your data." if I run the same script through pycharm (an IDE for python) everything works fine and when I log in I get a message on chrome saying "everything worked You can close this webpage". But if I do it in replit after I log in it give me this error:
[image: replit error]

If someone can help me that would be helpful! (I'm a beginner at api's so please be patient with me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is with the redirect back after the login. As you can see from the error message the `localhost` ([see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)) refused the connection. This is very much expected behavior as it's not the local machine running the code, but you're running it in the cloud when using replit.

The code sample you're using cannot be used directly using replit. What you *can* do is run the code locally once to create the token file and upload that to replit. Note that this solution is not advised, but I'm including it for your understanding.

The specific code section I'm talking about is:

```py
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

This part creates a `token.json` file after the login flow. If this file exists then the login flow is not used, as per this section of code:

```py
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
```

### Actual solution

The better solution is to replace the code below:

```py
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

with the code below:

```py
            creds = flow.run_console()
```

as described in the documentation for the library [here](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html#google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.run_console).

What this does is to print out a link which you need to visit in another browser window. It has more or less the same login flow as the `flow.run_local_server(port=0)` but instead of redirecting to `localhost` it generates a code which you need to paste in replit. It should be reasonably obvious to do and is meant for issues like the one you're experiencing.

This method can be used for example when you're remoted into a cloud machine that only has commandline. (fe. [headless computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_computer))

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!! It worked!!!
Thanks for explaining/simplifying it!

Comment: Hi, it's me again! your code worked so I think you know a bit about the API and python. I'm this close to finishing but I received another error:
Scope has changed from "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.files" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly".

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: so the scopes determine what API calls you can make. See this [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) for details. When you change the scopes you need to delete the existing `token.json` and do the login flow again. The `token.json` stores the scopes it was authenticated with. The other option would be to change the scopes in the code itself. It depends on what API calls you want to make. You should always use the scopes with least possible access to minimize security risks.

Comment: Note, in the code the scopes are set with this line: `SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I deleted the token.json and changed scopes to drive.metadata.readonly. I had to log in again with my google account and enter another authorization code. The code started running but sadly I received this error:
`BLA BLA BLA... returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}]">`

Comment: OK so that means that the scopes you now use in your code is not enough to actually perform the API call you're trying to do. You need to change it to a scope that allows you to perform the API call you're trying to do. Check the [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) I linked to see which scope you need. It is advised to chose the lowest possible scope. You then need to update the line in your code that declares the `SCOPES` variable, and delete the `token.json` and then do the login flow again.

Comment: OH NO!!!! I found the solution! I'm so sry for al these questions!
The problem was that I changed my scopes in replit and not in Pycharm so everything I clicked the link in pycharm (because the link form replit didn't work) I created authorize link from only the scope that was in my pycharm script. I changed the scopes in my pycharm script to be the exact same as in the replit file.... and it WORKS!!!!

I checked my google drive and I see the test.txt
Thanks you so much!!!

Comment: Geen probleem...